# Вывод звука в порт на Realtek High Defination Audio

Tags: windows, delphi, c++

Как выводить звук из программы на Realtek High Defination Audio, причем в определённый порт?

Есть два звуковых выхода: аналоговый и цифровой (т.е. на сист. блоке). Как выводить звук только в определённый порт. Может есть  API ? Где его найти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

High Definition Audio - это стандарт для шины-кодеков (прежде был ACLink). Прямо общаться с кодеком по шине можно из драйвера устройства, но не из приложения Delphi. Соответственно либо пишется пользовательский драйвер, который садится на кодек и как-то по особому с ним общается, либо используется системный драйвер и системный API и т.п.

Что предоставляет Windows? Это [Audio API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb945061.aspx). API позволяет пронумеровать точки выхода для работы (endpoint), например, динамики и выбрать желаемые. Вполне вероятно, что есть возможность выбрать и желаемый выход.